# heroku push rejected, failed to compile Python app

Tags: heroku, flask

I have created a python application using "Flask" a python framework. I used the following documentation https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/python

When I run this:

```
git push heroku master
```

I'm getting the following error after pushing to heroku.

```
Counting objects: 8, done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (4/4), done.
Writing objects: 100% (8/8), 1.62 KiB, done.
Total 8 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0)

-----> Python app detected
-----> No runtime.txt provided; assuming python-2.7.4.
-----> Preparing Python runtime (python-2.7.4)
-----> Installing Distribute (0.6.36)
-----> Installing Pip (1.3.1)
-----> Installing dependencies using Pip (1.3.1)
       Downloading/unpacking BeautifulSoup==3.2.1 (from -r requirements.txt (line 1))
         Downloading BeautifulSoup-3.2.1.tar.gz
         Running setup.py egg_info for package BeautifulSoup

       Downloading/unpacking CDApplet==1.0 (from -r requirements.txt (line 2))
         Could not find any downloads that satisfy the requirement CDApplet==1.0 (from -r requirements.txt (line 2))
       No distributions at all found for CDApplet==1.0 (from -r requirements.txt (line 2))
       Storing complete log in /app/.pip/pip.log

 !     Push rejected, failed to compile Python app

To git@heroku.com:frozen-brushlands-5131.git
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'git@heroku.com:frozen-brushlands-5131.git'
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like there is not a Python package called CDApplet. When your Heroku app tries to install CDApplet it fails and gives you this error.

I tried it locally and could not find a Python package called CDApplet either.

Answer (score 1):

I encountered the same error, try removing the concerned dependency (or add a correct name).
After that, do:
`git add .`

```
git commit -m "commit-message"
git push heroku master
```

You should be ready to go now.

Answer (score 0):

i have same problem and fixed with

```
git add *
git commit -m "initial commit"
git push heroku master
```

i hope this'll help you.

Answer (score 0):

I also ran into this problem, luckily, I found a fix. This are the steps I took.

**Step 1**
You need to upgrade the heroku app via command line interface

```
`$` heroku stack:set heroku-18 -a <app name>
```

**Note** that this will not affect previous apps that was built so you may need to rebuild the app. Remember to substitute "app name" with the name of the app

```
`$` git commit --allow-empty -m "Upgrading to heroku-18"
```

After the previous line, try pushing it again with:

```
`$` git push heroku master
```

**Step 2**
If this doesn't work remove the runtime.txt file containing the python version and remember to add and commit changes to git. Push once again and it should work, It worked for me!
[image: My CLI]